# GWT and j_security_check 302 found redirect

Tags: gwt, get, j-security-check

I have a web servlet that uses java security for authentication and authorization. When I authenticate myself using a GET /j_security_check?j_username=a&j_password=b through the browser, everything works fine.

On the other hand, when I try to access the same URL through a RequestBuilder using GWT I'm getting a 302 found response from the web server and I'm redirected at the root page followed by a jsessionid variable (www.myurl.com;jsessionid=blabla).

Shouldn't the behavior be the same ?

Comment: Just for clarity you are not passing password in "j_password=b" right? Hashed or Normal?

Comment: It's for testing purposes not for production mode. And yes I'm passing it as a query parameter in a get request. Both the username and the password.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure on your approach. We tend to go with 
Login.jsp (Client Submit) ---> Servlet Filter authentication - Servlet sets up server session with jsession id ---> On Success app gets redirected to GWT module html file.

All subsequent communication are over RPC ( XSRF token if you want to go secure ) and also additionally over https layer.